# show progress dialog from custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

I am trying to show a progress dialog from a custom dialog while an image get uploaded to a server. Here is what I have:

```
final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sendimage_dialog);
ImageView im = (ImageView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.image_to_upload);
                        im.setImageURI(Constants.currImageURI);

Button upload = (Button)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.upload);

upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    mDialog.dismiss();

});

mDialog.show();

mDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){

@Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface di) {

                                ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(CameraActivity.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
                                progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                                progress.setMessage("Please wait while your photo is being uploaded.");
                                progress.show();

                                String response = uploadUserPhoto(new File(getRealPathFromURI(Constants.currImageURI)));
                                try {
                                    parseResponse(response);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                progress.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Using your computer, log into your graFighters account and your image will be waiting for you.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        });
```

The problem is, when I hit the upload button, my progress dialog never shows. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're performing the network call (uploadUserPhoto) in the main (UI) thread, which means that the UI won't be updated between the calls to show() and dismiss(). If you want this to work, you could launch a separate worker Thread that performs the uploadUserPhoto instead. After the worker Thread has finished, it must then signal the Activity to remove the dialog.

Comment: I just edited my code to use OnDimissListener - do you think it is the same issue you just outlined?

Comment: I just solved by using a separate thread. You were right...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing and  dismissing your ProgressDialog in the click method. As for

```
mDialog.dismss
```

It should be dismissing. If you created a custom dialog we may need to see more of it to get a better idea.

EDIT: and then your calling the dialog to show outside of your onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `AlertDialog`. Here is an example that should fit your code pretty well:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Alert")
       .setMessage("Please wait while your photo is being uploaded.")
       .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               })
       .show();
```

I also recommend looking into using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).